# Телеграмм бот на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Суть такова: есть стрим на Ютубе :(https://www.youtube.com/live/WqzPWIafKuE?si=awy0Oll8KWU3aLJG) и мне нужно чтобы когда жужание прекращалось бот начал записывать аудио(ну или видео) с трансляции и сохранял куда нибудь себе на сервер, и как жужжание возобновлялось , то бот должен прекращать запись и скинуть в чат к себе данную запись. Я новичок в программировании поэтому не знаю как так сделать. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Прошу меня не пинать если буду задавать глупые вопросы)

Comment: Это не фриланс, а база знаний, мы за вас код писать не будем.

Comment: Задача звучит не сложно, но как уже сказали выше: бесплатно, а уж тем-более тут - писать за вас код никто не будет. Приходите с конкретными вопросами и своими попытками решения(код). Как альтернатива, нанимайте исполнителя.